# Story of a boy whose dreams are being recorded at school. Read in elementary school in the 80's

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching the the name of a story I read in the late 80's. It was in an elementary school Language Arts textbook, and may have been a short story or part of a novel. Bradbury's *All Summer in a Day* was also in this collection, so I'm guessing it's a similar author.

A boy is living in a school setting with other children. He is worried because today is his day to share his recorded dreams with the group, and he dreamt of assaulting another boy who was probably a bully. I think he kicked the boy off a balcony in the dream.

The details may be wrong, but that's how I remember it. Does anyone know what this might have been?

Comment: Here are the books "All Summer..." appeared in: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58363